# Match nonexhaustive im ML treemap function

Tags: tree, treemap, ml, non-exhaustive-patterns

Hello I am new to ML and am writing a treemap function for the following datatype :

```
     datatype tree = NIL | CONS of (tree * tree) | LEAF of int;
```

This is my treemap function:

```
fun treemap f = fn LEAF x => LEAF (f x)
            | CONS(y,z) => CONS (treemap f y, treemap f z);
```

I know I'm getting the nonexhaustive warning because I am not checking the NIL case, but how do I check for it? When I add another or I get an `EQUALOP` error. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the NIL case, try ad
|NIL => NIL;

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.